# Синхронная динамическая загрузка .DLL в нескольких потоках, возможно ли?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть библиотека на .NET

При синхронном вызове функций библиотеки из нескольких потоков моего приложения она работает некорректно (думаю из-за ее внутренних методов синхронизации). Т.е. есть некий метод Connect() в .dll, при вызове из разных потоков он срабатывает не синхронно, а последовательно.

Возможно ли сделать синхронную динамическую загрузку этой .dll, находящейся по одному и тому же пути, из разных потоков? Может быть есть друге решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы библиотеку можно было вызывать из разных потоков, она явно должна это поддерживать.

Путей параллельно использовать однопоточную библиотеку у вас несколько:

- Грузить библиотеку в разных процессах. Вам придётся создать столько дочерних процессов, сколько операций должно выполняться параллельно. Пуленепробиваемый способ, но тормозной.
- Грузить библиотеку в разных доменах приложения (app domains). Работает с управляемыми библиотеками.
- Скопировать библиотеку под другим именем. Взаимодействие с подобной библиотекой заметно усложнится: для нативной библиотеки придётся писать отдельные обёртки под каждый файл (или маршалить вручную), для управляемой библиотеки — разруливать конфликты с помощью алиасов.

Comment: Athari, по второму пункту хотел уточнить. Поможет ли он в моем случае (ведь используемая мной библиотека вместо синхронного поддерживает только последовательное выполнение)?

Comment: @z668 Должен помочь. Домены полностью изолируют управляемый код — это типа как процессы, только легковесные, и разделение работает только для управляемого кода. Но есть нюансы, конечно. Например, если этот Connect пишет в какой-то файл, и этот файл один на систему, то параллельный запуск невозможен.

Comment: Спасибо. Да нет, ни в файл, ни в реестр библиотека не пишет, рефлектором все тщательно просмотрел.

Comment: @z668 С процессами пробовали? Против лома нет приёма, что называется... Если взаимодействие не слишком плотное, то с процессами должно нормально работать.

Comment: Athari, с процессами в последнюю очередь т.к. не хочу использовать пайпы, мапить файлы и т.д.. Копаюсь с рефлексией сейчас. Параллельно еще другой софт пишу.